# How to stop wifi disconnection when eth0 link becomes ready?

Tags: 10.10, network-manager, wireless

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed on my laptop and connected via wireless lan to my home network.
Now I want to play around with my old wifi equipment which I need to configure first.
But every time I plug the ethernet cable in and the link on eth0 becomes ready Ubuntu disconnects my WLAN connection. Which is extremely annoying as I can't surf as along as I'm connected via (cable) ethernet.
Or generally speaking: As long as I'm connected with a network from the "wired" tab.

I already checked "Available to all users" for my WLAN and Wired network so that they are available when I log in. But this doesn't affect the problem mentioned above.

Do I need to get rid of the NetworkManager to be able to stay connected to my WLAN and Wired network at the same time?
(They don't share the same network address pool. WLAN is static IP, Wired is DHCP with differenct IP network.)

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to go in the connection's configuration settings, under the **IPv4 Settings** tab, click the **Routes** button, and check the checkbox marked "*Use this connection only for the resouces on its network*".

What this does is tell NetworkManager to not use that connection as a default route. However, you'll need to edit it again to remove that option if you want to use wired as a connection for the internet (or create a separate connection just for changing old wifi settings).

[image: where to change the settings]

Comment: I was having a similar issue when connecting my ubuntu 20 laptop to an embedded system equipped with Xavier AGX and this solution solved my problem! Thank you!