# select which network used for internet access

Tags: 10.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop wifi disconnection when eth0 link becomes ready?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37193/how-to-stop-wifi-disconnection-when-eth0-link-becomes-ready)

I have got two active network connections on my system:

- mobile broadband, DHCP to connect to internet via my ISP
- ethernet static IP for local subnet in home network

Whenever the ethernet connection is active, I lose my internet connection.

Ubuntu seems to be prefering the ethernet port for internet access...

**How can I setup my system to always use the mobile broadband for web access?**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be, that your static network sets the default gateway. That way, all your internet traffic gets then routed to some other machine without connection to the internet.

Have a look what

```
route
```

tells you. If the default gateway is set to s.th. different than your ISP's IP try:

```
route del default gw
route add default gw <IP of your ISP>
```

If that doesn't help, it would be useful to know your exact configuration of the two interfaces and the output of `route`.